# HTML5 Number Input Fails with decimal value

Tags: html, input, numbers

I have not confirmed if this is just an iOS error, but I'm facing this problem in my app.

This:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" disabled="disabled" name="cash_total" value="4.00" id="cash_total" placeholder="0.00"  />
```

Shows: 4

Even with the Step in there.  What's going on?!

UPDATE:  This is a Safari bug I've noticed, even on desktop: http://jsfiddle.net/S9msN/

Comment: `4` and `4.00` are the same number; what problem are you facing? How does it 'fail' for you?

Comment: Can you show us an example of it not working?

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  My app deals with finance and showing accuracy of displaying two decimal points is important.

Comment: Then you'll need to use JavaScript to format the number (usually some variation of `(Number).toFixed(2)`).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S9msN/ (view in Safari)

Comment: David: I've tried that, but the browser removes the decimal points when applying that value to the input field.

Comment: @Adam It works in Safari for me (Windows, v.5.1.7)..

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. When the page loads, it uses some js to do the math and then adjust the value: http://jsfiddle.net/LSnvj/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
jQuery(document).ready(  
    function(){  
        jQuery(window).load(function(){  
                var value = 4;
                var step = 0.01;
                var total = value+step;
                jQuery("#cash_total").attr("value",total);
        })
});  
-->
</script>

<input type="number" step="0.01" disabled="disabled" name="cash_total" value="0.00" id="cash_total" placeholder="0.00"  />
```